# Unable to set custom resolutions for the CameraX Preview and ImageAnalysis

Tags: android, android-camerax

I am using the following code snippet to analyze the camera Frames using Android CameraX API for selected resolutions. Using StreamConfigurationMap I am getting the compatible image resolutions based on the YUV_420_888 image format and camera ID.

```
String cameraID = AppSettings.getCurrentCamera(FaceCaptureActivity.this);
    cameraFacing = Integer.parseInt(cameraID);
    cameraSelector = new CameraSelector.Builder().requireLensFacing(cameraFacing).build();

    previewView.setScaleType(PreviewView.ScaleType.FIT_START);
    previewView.post(() ->{
        //Initialize CameraX
        cameraProviderFuture.addListener(() -> {

            try {
                if(cameraProvider != null){
                    cameraProvider.unbindAll();
                }

                cameraProvider = cameraProviderFuture.get();

                Preview preview = null;
                int[] resolution = AppSettings.getCamResolution(FaceCaptureActivity.this);
                if (resolution[0] == 0 || resolution[1] == 0) {
                    preview = new Preview.Builder()
                            .setTargetAspectRatio(AspectRatio.RATIO_4_3)
                            .setTargetRotation(previewView.getDisplay().getRotation())
                            .build();
                }else{
                    preview = new Preview.Builder()
                            .setTargetResolution(new Size(resolution[0], resolution[1]))
                            .setTargetRotation(previewView.getDisplay().getRotation())
                            .build();
                }

                ImageAnalysis imageAnalysis = new ImageAnalysis.Builder()
                        .setBackpressureStrategy(ImageAnalysis.STRATEGY_KEEP_ONLY_LATEST)
                        .setTargetResolution(new Size(resolution[0], resolution[1]))
                        .build();

                imageAnalysis.setAnalyzer(executor, new ImageAnalysis.Analyzer() {
                    @Override
                    public void analyze(@NonNull ImageProxy image) {
                        //Analyze the image
                    }
                });

                if (resolution[0] == 0 || resolution[1] == 0) {
                    imageCapture = new ImageCapture.Builder()
                            .setCaptureMode(ImageCapture.CAPTURE_MODE_MINIMIZE_LATENCY)
                            .setTargetRotation(previewView.getDisplay().getRotation())
                            .setTargetAspectRatio(AspectRatio.RATIO_4_3)
                            .build();
                }else{
                    imageCapture = new ImageCapture.Builder()
                            .setCaptureMode(ImageCapture.CAPTURE_MODE_MINIMIZE_LATENCY)
                            .setTargetRotation(previewView.getDisplay().getRotation())
                            .setTargetResolution(new Size(resolution[0], resolution[1]))
                            .build();
                }
                preview.setSurfaceProvider(previewView.createSurfaceProvider());
                Camera camera = cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle((LifecycleOwner)this, cameraSelector, preview, imageAnalysis,imageCapture);


            } catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(FaceCaptureActivity.this));
    });
```

But in the imageAnalaysis callback, I am receiving the same image width and height for the captured image frame, no matter which resolution I set to the preview and imageAnalaysis. Have I missed something in my code or is there any other way of doing this?

Comment: were u able to solve the problem? cause right now im stuck with the same problem

Comment: This issue has been resolved in the latest camerax API releases. Please check the documentation https://developer.android.com/training/camerax/configuration.